# Display data with tables vs forms vs tabs vs custom controls?

Tags: .net, winforms

I need to allow a user to process some data. Data is say 100 items which are tagged to say 10 different groups.

Each item contains data like name, quantity, reference which need to be displayed.

At the start of the process the program should take the items and place them into groups for display to user. Each group should also contain information common to the group eg Name, number of items.

The grouping won’t be 100% accurate; I need to allow the user to move items between groups. This should update the number of items in the common information.

I also need users to be able to add items from scratch, or edit or delete.  Ie like a datagridview.

Once all the data is in the correct groups, user pushes a process button and I then deal with the data.

My query is how best to present the data to the user ?

I’m fairly new to C# but making good progress. It’s a desktop winforms application. VS2010 with .net 4.

I’ve not yet done drag & drop or custom controls but I’m willing to use this project as a learning experience too.

I do realise that no matter which solution I go for, there will be a huge amount of display space required.

I could:

- Create a custom control with a datagrid for the items; fields for the common info; repeat as many custom controls as I need
- Create a form with datagrid & fields; have an MDI master form to contain the child forms
- Create a tabbed form with one tab per group; possibly have a “move to” control to move items off one tab to another.
- Use tables to create a long formatted list. Headers for each group appear at the start of each group; rows repeat underneath; create new rows inserts a row into table.

Any others I’ve missed ?

I’m hoping for some advice on the best way forward or some gotcha’s with some of the solutions.

I like the idea of custom controls in a long form. User starts at top and works their way down; moving and editing items as they come across them.

TIA, andrew

EDIT: THanks to Salazaar, but I realise on re-reading my intentions with groups may not be clear.

Here's an image of what I thought one control/section could look like. Invoices can be moved from one "destination" to another:

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I discovered that a really long list is unusable.

I've gone with a hybrid approach of using MDI child windows and a tab control in the MDI parent. So you can use tabs on the parent to bring up the MDI children; or click on the child windows to set focus.

Answer (score 0):

Hm i just love simple solutions, so i tried to create one:

[image]

At the top i use Buttons to Filter the Content of the Grid, Red means the Group is not displayed.
I choose Buttons over Checkboxes in this case, because i think they are handier and faster to work with.

Below is the "working area", a big grid with mich space for the Data. The First Column contains the Group and is Colored like the Buttons above.

At the bottom are the Buttons to Save or add new Rows etc.

The Groups would be changed with a Combobox Column (not in the Screenshot, sorry), so you can handle the group change with the other Data when the Save Button is pressed.

Hope that helpes.
Constructive critisism is appreciated.

Comment: I should have mentioned items can only be on one group. Your button idea is similar to my tabbed idea, perhaps uses less space 'cause two rows of buttons rather than a row of tabs; or really messy multiple rows of tabs like some MS apps. I really appreciate the effort to create a mock demo - thanks, andrew